# How do construct a electrical resistance tomography apparatus

Tags: electromagnetism, resistance, probe

Im interested in constructing an electrical resistive tomography setup to image underground structures. While I somewhat understand the principle, I have found limited information on design and construction. I'm looking for any information on how to construct one.

Comment: Which part of the design process is causing you trouble?

Comment: In New York City?? With electrified man hole covers and subway ground faults energizing the plumbing? You would be better off making a ground current map.